# WCF json endpoint not found

Tags: json, wcf, endpoint

I am new to WCF and was testing a simple example, with which I got stuck for too long. The error or things I missed might be stupid, but please help me with it. Thanks a lot in advance.

Here comes my description of the problem:

I was testing a WCF service with json enabled, which is implemented in my `CalService.svc.cs` file by the following code:

```
namespace SharePoint.WebServices
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalculators
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
        )]
        float Weight(float width, float diameter, float size, float factor);
    }

    public class Calculators : ICalculators
    {
        public float Weight(float width, float diameter, float size, float factor)
        {
        return 10f;
        }
    }
}
```

and my `CalService.svc` file is like this:

```
<%@ 
    ServiceHost 
    Language="C#" 
    Debug="true" 
    Service="SharePoint.WebServices.Calculators" 
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"
    CodeBehind="CalService.svc.cs" 
%>
```

I test it my sample service with IE. I was notified of the `no endpoint found` message. Thus, I think the problem comes from my web.config file. Here it is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service  name="SharePoint.WebServices.Calculators">
        <endpoint
            address=""
            behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="SharePoint.WebServices.ICalculators" />
        <endpoint
            address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
   </services>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I've checked all the points that are made by folks who replied similar threads regarding json-enabled wcf, but still had the endpoint issue. Please help!

Comment: Well, by default, the browser (like IE) can only execute `GET` commands - but your method expects a HTTP `POST`. You'll need to use a tool like Fiddler or something like that to send `POST` to your service - or add a second method that runs on a `GET` to your service so you can test it in the browser

Comment: And make sure the HTTP address you are hitting is correct. I would expect the URL for your POST method is something like this : http://localhost:port/CalService.svc/Weight with request body having something like this width=1&diameter=1&size=1&factor=1

Comment: I guess your are right. I definitely should try handcraft a HTTP Post request to the wcf service. But can you give me a sample of what the HTTP request would be raw format, expecially the body message that contains the parameter? Do you think the parameters are encoded as a JSON string in the HTTP body? I did some search on this, found nothing useful. I am trying to use Fiddler 4 as you suggested.Thanks a lot. @marc_s